# When using acts-as-taggable-on gem in Rails, is it possible to delete orphaned tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I just deleted all the posts in my app. But the tags are still there. Even if we delete all the posts the tags won't get deleted. How can we detect and delete all the tags which are not linked to any posts?

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration setting you can add to `config/application.rb` to make sure tags get deleted when they are no longer used:

`ActsAsTaggableOn.remove_unused_tags = true`

You can also put this in an initializer under `config/initializers`.

Source: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#configuration

Answer (score 0):

This SQL query will give you the number of times the tag is used in taggings:

```
SELECT tags.id, COUNT(taggings.id) from
tags JOIN taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY tags.id
ORDER BY COUNT(taggings.id) ASC;
```

Next up you can put this in a subselect and delete all the tags that have COUNT(taggings.id) = 0.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT tags.id, COUNT(taggings.id) as times_used from
tags JOIN taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY tags.id
ORDER BY COUNT(taggings.id) ASC) as tag_stats
WHERE times_used = 0;
```

You can then change that to a delete statement.